# Fechas duplicadas en Chart

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel

Siguiendo con mi proyecto en laravel estoy intentando hacer una grafica Chart, pero al momento de traducir las fechas por meses me duplica el resultado, pero cuando lo dejo en ingles me va de maravilla dudo mucho que sea la consulta pero igual dejo la informacion para ver si me hechan una mano. Desde ya muchas gracias...

Este es el codigo que ingreso dentro de la etiqueta **labels**

```
labels: [
            <?php 
                foreach ($ingresosMes as $reg) {
                    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES', 'Spanish_Spain', 'Spanish');
                    $mes_traducido=strftime('%B',strtotime($reg->mes));
                    echo '"'.$mes_traducido.'",';
                }                
            ?>
            ],
```

Vista previa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin traduccion:

```
labels: [
            <?php 
                foreach ($ingresosMes as $reg) {
                    echo '"'.$reg->mes.'",';
                }                
            ?>
            ],
```

Vista previa:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver cuando intento traducir los meses a español me dublica el registro, pero cuando la dejo por defecto me bota tal cual.

Espero puedan ayudarme, los leo.
Muchas gracias de antemano

Dejo el codigo del CHART

```
var areaChartCanvas = $('#areaChart').get(0).getContext('2d')

        var areaChartData = {
            labels: [
            <?php 
                foreach ($ingresosMes as $reg) {
                    echo '"'.$reg->mes.'",';
                }                
            ?>
            ],
            datasets: [{
                    label: 'Ingresos',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(60,141,188,0.9)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(60,141,188,0.8)',
                    pointRadius: false,
                    pointColor: '#3b8bba',
                    pointStrokeColor: 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
                    pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
                    pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
                    data: [
                        <?php foreach ($ingresosMes as $reg)
                        {
                            echo ''.$reg->totalmes.',';
                        }
                        ?>
                    ]
                },
                {
                    label: 'Gastos',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
                    pointRadius: false,
                    pointColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
                    pointStrokeColor: '#c1c7d1',
                    pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
                    pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 31, 32, 75, 65, 19, 86, 47]
                },
            ]
        }

        var areaChartOptions = {
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            responsive: true,
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false,
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false,
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
```

Comment: Usas php o componentes de laravel?

Comment: yo creo que no sólo está traduciendo, sino recalculando la diferencia horaria. Por eso los meses de 31 días  cuadran, mientras que los de 28 y 30 aparecen como si fueran del mes siguiente.